# Load frequent subsequences from TXT

Tags: r, traminer

Is it possible to load a list of frequent subsequences from a .txt file, and make TraMineR recognize it as a sequence object?

Unfortunately I don't have the raw data, therefore I am not able to recreate the analysis. The only file what I have is a .txt file containing the frequent subsequences. I assume it was created with the `seqefsub()` function from the TraMineR package, with `maxGap=2`, because the data looks like as an output of the mentioned function.

`read.table()` reads it as a data frame but as far as I understood, TraMineR handles event sequences as lists with many additional attributes, that for example are not contained in this file. Or I don't know how to extract them...

This is how the a couple of lines from the .txt file look like:

```
                                             Subsequence    Support  Count
16                                           (WT4)-(WT3) 0.76666667    805
17                                                 (WL2) 0.76380952    802
18                                                  (S1) 0.76000000    798
19                                             (FRF,WL2) 0.74380952    781
20                                           (WT2)-(WT1) 0.70571429    741
```

Comment: Why do you want to save the print of the outcome of `seqefsub` as text and then read it back as sequence object? The `seqefsub` function already returns an event sequence object. Do you want to transform the event sequence object into a state sequence object? (if yes look at [http://stackoverflow.com/a/28968342/1586731] ). Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Gilbert – I've edited my question, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an event sequence object from the (text) subsequences, you have to transform them into vertical time stamped event (TSE) form. The function below does the job for your data

```
## Function subseq.to.TSE
##  puts the sequences into TSE format using
##  position as timestamp
##  sdf: a data frame with columns Id, Subsequence, Support and Count.

subseq.to.TSE <- function(sdf){
  tse <- data.frame(id=0, event="", time=0)
  k <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(sdf)){
    id <- sdf[i,"Id"]
    s <- sdf[i,"Subsequence"]
    ss <- gsub("\\(","",s)
    ss <- gsub("\\)","",ss)
    # split transitions
    st <- strsplit(ss, split="-")[[1]]
    for (j in 1:length(st)){
      stt <- strsplit(st[j], split=",")[[1]]
      for(jj in 1:length(stt)){
        k <- k+1
        tse[k,1] <- id
        ## parsing for simultaneous events
        if (!(stt[jj] %in% levels(tse[,2])))
          {levels(tse[,2]) <- c(levels(tse[,2]),stt[jj])}
        tse[k,2] <- stt[jj]
        tse[k,3] <- j
      }
    }
  }

  return(tse)
 }
```

Here is how you would use it on the example data.

We first create the data frame that we name `s.df`

```
s.df <- data.frame(scan(what=list(Id=0, Subsequence="", Support=double(), Count=0)))
16 (WT4)-(WT3) 0.76666667    805
17 (WL2) 0.76380952    802
18 (S1) 0.76000000    798
19 (FRF,WL2) 0.74380952    781
20 (WT2)-(WT1) 0.70571429    741

# leave a blank line to end the scan
```

Then we extract the TSE data from `s.df` and create from it the event sequence object using `seqecreate`. Finally, we assign the counts as sequence weights.

```
s.tse <- subseq.to.TSE(s.df)
seqe <- seqecreate(s.tse)
seqeweight(seqe) <- s.df[,"Count"]
```

Now you can for instance plot the event sequences with

```
seqpcplot(seqe)
```